# CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION in HSQLDB

Tags: hsqldb, sql-function

When creating a function, Oracle allows the following syntax:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
```

Is something similar also possible in HSQL? I.e. creating a function, avoiding an error if it already exists and replacing it instead?

Comment: [The manual](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#src_routine_definition) doesn't show such a syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CREATE OR REPLACE is supported in ORA compatibility mode but it works only when the function does not exist.

The ALTER SPECIFIC ROUTINE syntax is supported when the function does exist and allows you to change the body of the function without changing its parameter.

You can use SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES to check if a function exists.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to find out if a function exists in HSQL?